# Taking snapshot of sharepoint infopath form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

programatically i want to take snapshot of a infopath form which is in formlibrary. I have used many third party tools they all working fine for other sites. but it is not working correctly for sharepoint sites. If it works for sharepoint sites it is not able to do for infopath form.

When i try to take snapshot of a infopath form the ribbon controls are coming the output but the needed form is not in the pdf output. Is infopath is a silverlight application. Why i am not able to take snapshot of that . Any idea.

Comment: Might help if you give us an idea of what you're using currently that doesn't capture the form!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear, but you mention PDF so it sounds like you want to take PDF based snapshots from your InfoPath form.

[Have a look at this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/batch-print-infopath-forms-using-pdf.html) that I wrote some time ago. It uses a (our) third party product for converting files in SharePoint, including InfoPath, to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I have a less cost solutions for you if you are interested:

1. use a builded workflow ( http://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-pdf-sharepoint-workflow-31202.html ) to be able to convert a form into a library.
2. use iTextSharp with c# to code your form into PDF by this steps:
   a. create the pdf in memorystream.
   b. encode your pdf into an attachment using this: ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2517906 )

G o o d   L u c k ! ! !